# Use array in jquery to count through numbers 1-4

Tags: jquery

I would like to shorten the following code snippet. Basically, I would like to count through from 1 to 4 and if I remember correctly I could do this with an array?

```
    $('.anchor-4').on('click', function(event){
        $('#ui-id-4').click();
    });
    $('.anchor-3').on('click', function(event){
        $('#ui-id-3').click();
    });
    $('.anchor-2').on('click', function(event){
        $('#ui-id-2').click();
    });
    $('.anchor-1').on('click', function(event){
        $('#ui-id-1').click();
    });
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++){
    $('.anchor-'+i).on('click', function(event){

            $('#ui-id-'+i).click();

        });
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'd like to implement it in the theme backend of my wordpress site (working with bridge theme). There I have to change the selector because of conflict mode to $j which I did but doesn't seem to work either. Also, on every click I get the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could prepopulate an array

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach(n => {
  $(`.anchor-${n}`).on('click', function(){
     $(`#ui-id-${n}`).click();
  });
});
```

if the N is unknown than you could use the `data-*` attribute to store the target selector

```js
// Use the attribute like: <a data-target="#ui-id-1" ...

$('[data-target]').on('click', function(){
   $(this.dataset.target).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this m assuming html something like this you can do

```
<div class="achor" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="achor" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="achor" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="achor" data-id="4"></div>


 $('.anchor').on('click', function(event){
    let id=$(this).data('id')
        $('#ui-id-'+id).click();

    });
```